# ^ operator gives different answer with using math function

Tags: python

The expression, `total = 2 ^ 1 - 1`, returns `2`.
Could anyone explain why it returns `2`?
Doesn't it suppose to return `1`?
What is the difference between this and using math function?

```
total = (math.pow(2,1) - 1)
```

Comment: the `^` does not signify exponentiation, it is the XOR operator

Comment: Isn't exponentiation a `**` in python?  As in `2**3` returns `8`.

Comment: Also see [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 0):

That's the "Bitwise Exclusive Or" operator, not the power/exponent operator.

So for your example, it converts the decimal values to binary, and then does XOR on each bit (where matching values are false and contradicting values are true). total = `10` (2decimal) xor `01` (1 decimal) = `11` (3 decimal). Subtract 1 and you get 2, as expected.

The operator your thinking of is "Exponentiation" ie `total = 2**1 - 1`

If you haven't, you'll learn about this in discrete math.

Answer (score 0):

`^` is the bitwise [XOR operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) in Python, not the power function.

Doing `2 ^ 1` does the following:

```
 10 # 2 in binary
 01 # 1 in binary
---
 11 # exclusive or
```

Which results in 3 in decimal, subtracted by 1 gives 2.

The math function is the proper power function. Alternatively, you can use `**` for exponentiation, as in `2**1`.